# Executing scripts that read from most recent USB udev plugged in device

Tags: linux, bash, usb, udev

As of right now, I've got my udev setup to execute scripts when a USB flash drive is plugged in or removed, but I'm stuck trying to figure out if there is some way that I can execute a script to read a file from the most recent USB device plugged in.

I am using usbmount to automatically mount all of my flash drives, and they are mounted according to this scheme:

`/dev/sdb1        15G  8.0K   15G   1% /media/usb0
/dev/sdc1        15G  8.0K   15G   1% /media/usb1
/dev/sdd1        15G  8.0K   15G   1% /media/usb2
/dev/sde1        15G  8.0K   15G   1% /media/usb3`

So for example, when I plug in USB flash drive #5, it gets automounted to /media/usb4, then I would like to say execute 'cat /media/usb4/data.txt > /tmp/output.txt' and only that drive that was just plugged in. Ideally I would like this to work no matter the number assigned to /media/usbx, so that if I replug in device 2, it would execute the script just for that device and not the rest.

Any ideas of how this can be done through bash scripting preferably but open to other ideas.

Thank you for your time.

------------- EDIT

I figured out a way although it's definitely not the prettiest or maybe even the most reliable:

```
$ sudo tail -n2 /var/log/syslog
Oct  4 14:40:58 development usbmount[32250]: executing command: mount -tvfat -osync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/sda1 /media/usb0
Oct  4 14:40:58 development usbmount[32250]: executing command: run-parts /etc/usbmount/mount.d
$
```

OK, so now to cut that down to just the media mount point,

```
$ sudo tail -n2 /var/log/syslog |grep media | awk '{print $12}'
/media/usb0
$
```

With this assuming no other errors or anything filling the last two spots on the syslog, I can execute scripts using something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
device=`sudo tail -n2 /var/log/syslog |grep media | awk '{print $12}'`

cat $device/data.txt > /tmp/output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run-parts` bit is a tip-off...you can create a file */etc/usbmount/mount.d/50_copydata*

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
[[ -f "${UM_MOUNTPOINT}/data.txt" ]] && cat "${UM_MOUNTPOINT}/data.txt" > /tmp/output.txt
```

`usbmount` will set $UM_MOUNTPOINT to i.e. */media/usb0*. I use `set -u` to make sure it only executes if $UM_MOUNTPOINT is set.

I assume you are going to filter the data - if you are only going to `cat` the file you might as well use `cp`.

Remember to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/usbmount/mount.d/50_copydata
```

Unplug and re-plug your device(s) to test. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, I didn't really poke around with those directories and did not assume they functioned the same as the udev directories for completing actions on start up. Thank you so much, worked like a charm! I was using a udev script to execute instead of the usbmount equiv.